# Laravel : force refresh extended view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I think, that i have a cache problem with a view when i extends a blade template.
The result should be :

```
Before : 578
Parent : 578
Section : 578
```

and i have :

```
Before : 578
Parent : 576
Section : 578
```

The parent template get an other id from somewhere ? Cache ?

This is my code :

```
//BlocController
public function edit(Bloc $bloc)
{
$content = view('blocs.'.$bloc->bloc_type.'.edit')
->with('bloc', $bloc);

return $content;
}
```

//Template called

```
Before : {{$bloc->id}}
@extends('blocs.edit')
@section('form_fields')
    Section : {{$bloc->id}}
@endsection
```

//Template blocs.edit

```
Parent : {{$bloc->id}}
@yield('form_fields')
```

Any idea ?

Thanks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. I used a view composer and use the parameter i pass in the url to get my $bloc before i send it to the parent view

//app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    View::composer('blocs.edit', function ($view) {
    $bloc = Request::route()->parameter('bloc');
    $view->with(['bloc' => $bloc]);
});
}
```